# How to call C++ method with signature std::list from C using extern?

Tags: c

I have a C++ method which takes a `std::list` as a function parameter; it populates that list when called.

I want to call this method from C using `extern`.

How can I match function parameter while calling from C?

Please find below pseudo code:

```
void getlist(std::list<Object *object> list)
{
    list.push_back("A");
}

extern "C"
{
    void list()
    {
        getlist(/*?*/);
    }
}
```

So, how can I make call to `getlist` method with required parameter?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to call `getlist` from a C++ function declared with `extern "C"` (as your code suggests), or how to call `getlist` from a function actually written in C (as the question's text suggests)?

Comment: Actually that getlist method is written into C++ language where I am filling that list and that extern C method I need to make call from another C class. I want to know how can I call that getlist method because C doesn't support std::list.

Comment: Still unclear, I'm afraid. I your code, `list()` has a C language linkage (= its name is not mangled), but it's still C++ code. If you're just going to use `std::list` internally inside `list`, you can use it as you would in any other C++ function. Or are you somehow trying to export that `std::list` into C?

Comment: Please, don't tag C++ specific questions as C, as you are making people waste time unnecessarily

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you would have to rely on `void*` to communicate your interface in C.

```
extern "C" void getlist(void *list_) {
  std::list<Object*> *list = static_cast<std::list<Object*>*>(list_);
  list->push_back("A");
}
```

For example you would have to **create** your list as:

```
extern "C" void* create_list(void) {
  return new std::list<Object*>;
}
```

You would have to **append** in your list as:

```
extern "C" void list_append(void *list_, void *obj_) {
  std::list<Object*> *list = static_cast<std::list<Object*>*>(list_);
  list->push_back(static_cast<Object*>(obj_));
}
```

And eventually you would have to **destroy** your list to avoid memory leaks as:

```
extern "C" void delete_list(void *list_) {
  delete static_cast<std::list<Object*>*>(list_);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't; that's impossible. To do so would require you to be able to declare a C++ class in C, which is impossible.

However, what you *can* do is to create a function which takes a `void*` as argument, and which casts that argument to an `std::list*` (that is, a pointer to an `std::list`). You can call that from C. Obviously such a function would need some support functions, such as a function to create the list, and one to destroy it.